# how to pass Float in Swift in Dictionary into ObjectiveC method as NSDictionary without turning it into a String?

Tags: objective-c, json, swift

ObjC method:

```
- (void)postRequestToURN:(NSString *)URN
          parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
```

Swift code calling it:

```
   var paramTest:NSDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    paramTest.setValue( Int(amount), forKey:"autopayAmt" )
    paramTest.setValue( Float(amount), forKey:"autopayAmt1" )
    paramTest.setValue( Double(amount), forKey:"autopayAmt2" )
    paramTest.setValue( (amount as NSNumber), forKey:"autopayAmt3" )
    paramTest.setValue( true, forKey:"autopayAmt4" )
```

Note: this must be some Swift mapping thing. On Swift 3 as of now. When I put the code with NSDictionary as the parameter then I get this compile error message. This doesn't really make sense as the parameter is an NSDictionary *  in the ObjectiveC code.

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSDictionary' to expected argument type '[AnyHashable : Any]!'
```

instead of numbers being in the JSON, I get strings. I need numbers.

```
{
autopayAmt = 125;
autopayAmt1 = "125.43";
autopayAmt2 = "125.4300003051758";
autopayAmt3 = "125.43";
autopayAmt4 = 1;
}
```

in the Objective C code the method parameters is passed as:

```
parameters  _TtGCs26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionaryVs11AnyHashableP__ *  0x608000038260  0x0000608000038260
```

Looks like its goofed up when it goes from the Swift code to the ObjC code. Here's what I print when in ObjectiveC code:

```
(lldb) po parameters
{
autopayAmt = 125;
autopayAmt1 = "125.43";
autopayAmt2 = "125.4300003051758";
autopayAmt3 = "125.43";
autopayAmt4 = 1;
}
```

versus if I click up in the stack to the Swift code and print then I see this:

```
lldb) po paramTest
▿ 5 elements
▿ 0 : 2 elements
- key : autopayAmt
- value : 125
▿ 1 : 2 elements
- key : autopayAmt2
- value : 125.4300003051758
▿ 2 : 2 elements
- key : autopayAmt1
- value : 125.43
▿ 3 : 2 elements
- key : autopayAmt4
- value : 1
▿ 4 : 2 elements
- key : autopayAmt3
- value : 125.43
```

I just want to know how to pass floats as numbers so they will be sent that way to the JSON server. Data of type Int does output as numbers...

Comment: If you get compiler errors then how can you *run* the code (and get strings instead of numbers)?

Comment: Most probably this is just a problem of how the `description` method of `NSDictionary` works. Try `NSLog(@"%@", @{ @"key": @12.345 });` which prints `{ key = "12.345"; }` even though the value is an NSNumber.

Comment: Try printing the class name, e.g. `po [parameters[@"autopayAmt1"] className]`, if you get a NSNumber family instance then the numbers are correctly stored

Comment: egad! Thanks Martin R and Cristik. These look right. The server was getting the correct data (as JSON number). So, error must have been another issue on server or such. So, looks like this "bug" was a factor of my debugging. If you want to post an answer then I can accept it.